# Rectangle and Circle collision detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to do collision detection between a rectangle and a circle. I came up with this method:

```
-(BOOL) isCollidingRect:(CCSprite *) spriteOne WithSphere:(CCSprite *) spriteTwo {
    float diff = ccpDistance(spriteOne.position, spriteTwo.position);
    float obj1Radii = [spriteOne boundingBox].size.width/2;
    float obj2Radii = [spriteTwo boundingBox].size.width/2;
    if (diff < obj1Radii + obj2Radii) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

and this is how I check it:

```
if ([self isCollidingRect:player WithSphere:blocker] == true) {
   [self playerdeathstart];
}
```

This seems to work properly on the side of the rectangle but it doesn't above or below it. On the top and bottom, the collision occurs too early.

[image: Kinda Like this..]

Is there a way I can get this collision to detected properly? Thank you for your help.

Comment: incidentally, please use `YES` and `NO` if you are returning a `BOOL`. Also you can just return the result of the comparison and avoid the if/else altogether.

Comment: Thanks! I updated this in my question.

Comment: It would be even better if you do `return (diff < obj1Radii + obj2Radii)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CGRectIntersectsRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) to achieve this.

```
-(BOOL) isCollidingRect:(CCSprite *) spriteOne WithSphere:(CCSprite *) spriteTwo {
    return CGRectIntersectsRect([spriteOne boundingBox],[spriteTwo boundingBox]);
}
```

It is not pixel perfect but as i understand that is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! Also, i think you forgot a parenthesis after `[spriteTwo boundingBox]`.

Comment: This will return TRUE when the circle's bounding box is within the rectangle's, not the circle itself. see: http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1UsZAiYadMHwyToj3ruWOKms2gAAb0.png

Comment: That is true, but as i said it is not pixel perfect but merely good enough for this case, and most game situations

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for those who use Cocos2d-ObjC, but will help for Cocos2d-x devs (for instance, personally I found this topic because was searching for the same for my c++ game).

Cocos2d-x has method "intersectsCircle" for Rect class.

Here is how I solved in my c++ project almost the same problem as one described by you:

```
bool ObstacleEntity::hasCollisionAgainst(cocos2d::Sprite *spr)
{
    cocos2d::Rect rect = cocos2d::Rect( spr->getPositionX(), spr->getPositionY(), spr->getBoundingBox().size.width, spr->getBoundingBox().size.height);

    float rw = this->getBoundingBox().size.width / 2;
    float rh = this->getBoundingBox().size.height / 2;

    float radius = ( rw > rh ) ? rw : rh;
    cocos2d::Vec2 center( this->getPositionX() + rw, this->getPositionY() + rh );

    return rect.intersectsCircle( center, radius );
}
```

Passed Sprite here is rectangle, while ObstacleEntity always is almost ideally round.
Note that anchor points for all entities are set to lower left corner in my case.

Comment: Added some details on my solution.